# vb.net OpenWeatherMap using HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, weather-api, openweathermap

I am unable to get the HttpWebRequest to work properly with OpenWeatherMap.

When I try out the URL from the browser I get the data. However, when I am sending it from the program I'm getting a message with code id. Like this:

```
"message":"","cod":"404"
```

What Am I doing wrong?

---

#### VB.NET Code:

```
    Private Shared AppID As String = "add_app_id_Here"
Public Shared Function GetWeather(ByVal location As String) As List(Of WeatherDetails)
    Dim url = String.Format _
        ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={0}&type=accurate&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=3&appid={1}",
         location, AppID)
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.AuthenticationLevel = Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        'The body of the request is sent here
        Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseInfo As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
        responseReader.Close()
        response.Close()
        If Not (responseInfo.Contains("message") And responseInfo.Contains("cod")) Then
            Dim xEl = XElement.Load(New System.IO.StringReader(responseInfo))
            Return GetWeatherInfo(xEl)
        Else
            Return New List(Of WeatherDetails)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New List(Of WeatherDetails)
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my head I found that his method HttpWebRequest is not tolerant to special characters or non printable characters.
Thus in the URL I had to hardcode the "%27" character and it solved the problem.